# Any way to preview .msg files in navigator?

Tags: html, preview

I have differents **.msg** files in my server and other files (**.docx**, **.mp3**, **.jpg** ...etc), there is some way to preview **.msg** files in navigator?. Something similar as preview office documents with google viewer.

Example:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.snee.com/xml/xslt/sample.doc&embedded=true" style="width:500px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want similar

```
<iframe src="http://urlexample.com/emailexample.msg" style="width:500px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Thanks.

[This page](https://www.encryptomatic.com/viewer/) can show this kind of files, I want to do something similar.

Answer (score -1):

The **object** element can represent an external resource, which, depending on the type of the resource, will either be treated as an image, as a nested browsing context, or as an external resource to be processed by a plugin.

The **data** attribute in , if present, specifies the address of the resource. If present, the attribute must be a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces.

The **type** attribute in , if present, specifies the type of the resource. If present, the attribute must be a valid mime type.

In your case,
e.g.

```
<object data="http://urlexample.com/emailexample.msg" type="application/vnd.ms-outlook" width="500" height="500">
       <embed src="http://urlexample.com/emailexample.msg" type="application/vnd.ms-outlook" />
</object>
```

Comment: can I use this wth de URL of the .msg file? like http://urlexample.com/emailexample.msg

Comment: I tried to use this, I placed the URL in the data field, and it don't worked, it tried to download the file :c

Comment: This page can show the .msg files that I load, I want do something similar jaja, look https://www.encryptomatic.com/viewer/

Comment: Try nesting <embed> inside <object> as shown in recent edit of the answer. I also have added content type as 'type' attribute. You should modify it depending upon your type value.

Comment: In Chrome, when I tried It, showed the message "The component is not compatible.". I only changed the URL from your example, for a real URL.

Comment: @FabianMontoya Hey, i know its an old question, but did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Tim-Bolhoeve, no, I didn't work more in this project and this feature was removed